# Is microtype fully supported now by XeLaTeX? If not, how can I keep myself up-to-date?

Tags: xetex, microtype

Is `microtype` fully supported now by XeLaTeX? If not, how can I keep myself up-to-date on this argument?

Comment: There's still some features that are pdftex only, such as kerning. You may check tlcontrib.metatex.org every once in a while for the most recent version.

Comment: Does the microtype support depend on the used font in xelatex?

Comment: @student I don't think so.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following table from the [microtype](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) (page 6) shows which of the micro-typographic features are available for the various engines:

[image: availability of microtypographic features]

As can be seen in the last line, `xetex` only supports *protrusion*.

Some time ago, it was rumoured that *font expansion* would be added to `xetex`, too, but it seems that there haven't been any developments in this area (or any, for that matter) recently.

*Tracking (aka letterspacing)* with `xetex` can be achieved with `fontspec` and its `LetterSpace` font feature option.

To stay up to date it should be sufficient to keep your tex system up to date, and for new `microtype` versions check the Change history.

Comment: not enabled mean that if I say only \usepackage{microtype} that feature will not be enabled right?

Comment: @FormlessCloud exactly, these features are available but not enabled by default -- you have to explicitly ask for them.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use kenring with LuaTeX? Maybe a beta version or forcing it?.  If not, how (or other package) can I get kerning with LuaTeX

Comment: @Robert When will the "kerning" microtye option be available for LuaTeX. Or how to get the same result with some simple LuaTeX parameter?