# Loading microtype before or after the font

Tags: microtype

According to the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586/9077), the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package should be loaded after the font, since `microtype` "needs to know what fonts are in use at the time that it is loaded". I am, however, not able to detect any difference between loading `microtype` before and after setting the font. I also notice that in the MWE below, the `mt-*.cfg` file for [`EB Garamond`](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/) is loaded *after* [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec), even if `microtype` is loaded first.

Does this mean that it simply doesn't matter when `microtype` is loaded?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype,polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{english}
\usepackage{blindtext,fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}

(simplified and abbreviated output below)
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013/W32TeX)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.sty)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/microtype.cfg)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/polyglossia/polyglossia.sty)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg)
(c:/texlive2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/ebgaramond/mt-EBGaramond.cfg)
```

Comment: `mt-EBGaramond.cfg` is not loaded here even if `microtype` is loaded second. I can't detect a difference but for a different reason: `mt-EBGaramond.cfg` is not loaded either way. However, I had to change your code to get it to compile and use `EB Garamond 12` as the font name. So maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: @cfr I don't understand. ``mt-EBGaramond.cfg`` is not loaded? According to the log, it is, as seen in my MWE. I also don't understand what you mean by "maybe that makes a difference?"

Comment: What I mean is: when I compile your code, it is not loaded. Except that I had to alter your code to get it to compile. Without the `12` I just get errors. With the `12`, it compiles but it never loads the `cfg` file regardless. It is in your log, but not mine!

Comment: Since you’re using XeTeX with `microtype` you should know about the [limitations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118926/41085) this combination has.

Comment: @cfr I see. That's a problem at your end, since the ``EB Garamond`` font is supposed to load without specifying the optical size. But this has nothing to do with my ``microtype`` question, so let's leave that aside.
@Crissov I do, but ``pdflatex`` is not an option for me, since I need to use larger fonts. And ``lualatex`` has other limitations, such as not being able to compile with ``pstricks``.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `microtype` can be loaded at any time as its actual font setup is deferred until the end of the preamble. The restriction that the package should be loaded after the fonts dates back to very old `microtype` versions (older than `v1.9a (2005/12/05)`). (I've fixed this in the answer you link to.)

There's only one caveat concerning loading order (see "Hints and Caveats"), which doesn't apply to your case, just mentioning it for completeness' sake: when loading `microtype` with the `babel` option, you have to load the `babel` (or `polyglossia`) package first.

[EDIT: as mentioned by @koppor in the comment below, `fontspec` no longer needs to be loaded first (since `v2.6`).]

Comment: The fontspec loading requirement seems to have gone in the meanwhile. Checked v2.7a of 2018-01-14. See also https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-pkgloader/pull/21#issuecomment-379025839.