# Pros and cons of kerning, spacing, and tracking in microtype

Tags: typography, microtype

As noted in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/118926/19809), kerning, spacing, and tracking are turned off by default in `microtype`. Why is that? Are there good arguments *against* using it? What would be the pros and cons of activating it?

Now that we're at it, what are the pros and cons of the other options (protrusion, expansion, =auto)?